# How does one access all form fields in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Sinatra makes it easy to access any particular incoming form field by name:

```
post "/" do
  params['form_field_name']
end
```

But how does one enumerate over *all* the form fields in a request?  I found nothing in the documentation.  I even tried

```
request.body.split('&')
```

but request.body is an instance of StringIO, and not a string.

Answer (score 10):

If `params` is a hash, you can try:

```
params.keys.each do |k|
   puts "#{k} - #{params[k]}"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered in Sinatra's excellent API docs that Sinatra::Request is a subclass of Rack::Request.  The request object available to Sinatra handlers inherits has a POST method which returns a hash of submitted form fields.

```
request.POST.each { |k,v| puts "#{k} = #{v}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

its just a hash :P so just iterate it like you would with any hash

Comment: Yes, params is a hash - but it is "the union of GET and POST data" as the Rack API docs put it.  I needed a way to find just the POST data, so the request.POST method is ideal.